# Ubuntu 14.04: spontaneously lost sound

Tags: 14.04, sound, soundcard

Rebooting today I noticed I have lost my sound device overnight:

```
$ sudo aplay -l
aplay: device_list:268: no soundcards found...
```

```
$ lspci -v | grep -A7 -i audio
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 7270
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 10
    Memory at e0730000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: < access denied >

00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
```

No Kernel driver in use and Kernel modules. I'd reckon that is not good.

Thought I need to have kernal module snd-hda-intel running.

```
$ locate locate snd-hda-intel
/lib/modules/3.13.0-37-generic/updates/kernel/snd-hda-intel.ko
/var/lib/dkms/oem-audio-hda-daily/original_module/3.13.0-37-generic/amd64/snd-hda-intel.ko
```

Any tip how to sort this?

By the way, as you can probably see above, I have the PPA Ubuntu-audio-dev/alsa-daily enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Try force reloading `Alsa`. To do that, use the following command in terminal<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

```
sudo alsa force-reload
```

After force reload it may seemed to be like hanged or still in process .. No need to get panic. It may take some couple of seconds. You can simply close it afterwards by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>^<kbd>C</kbd>

Now, you need to reboot your computer..

Comment: Thanks for the swift reply! I tried that. Didn't change anything.

Comment: Solved the problem: upgraded from kernel 3.13.0-37-generic to 3.16.0-31-generic

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and tried a lot of things such as reloading Alsa and even reinstalling it nothing helped. I updated to the 3.16 kernel version. I used this command to update the kernel on 14.04 `sudo apt-get install linux-image-generic-lts-utopic`